# How to use Rx to poll for images over an async WCF service

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have an async WCF service that takes a "URI" and returns an image (as a Stream).

Want I want to do is:

- Ensure a valid WCF channel exists, if no create it
- Make the async service call
- On success save the image to a member variable
- If I get an exception, close the channel
- Whether it fails or succeeds, wait 200ms then start again (looping forever or until cancelled)

So far I have come up with this monstrosity:

```
    private void PollImage(string imageUri)
    {
        const int pollingHertz = 1;
        const int millisecondsTimeout = 1000 / pollingHertz;
        Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);

        if (_channel == null)
        {
            _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        }

        var getImageFunc = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, Stream>
                                  (_channel.BeginGetImage, _channel.EndGetImage);

        getImageFunc(imageUri)
            .Finally(() => PollImage(imageUri))
            .Subscribe(
                stream => UpdateImageStream(imageUri, stream),
                ex =>
                    {
                        Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
                        ((ICommunicationObject) _channel).CloseOrAbort();
                        _channel = null;
                    });
    }
```

I really want to learn Rx but each time I try I get left scratching my head.

Anyone care to give me some pointers on this? Thanks

Comment: How to use Rx to elegantly solve the bullet points

Answer (score 7):

I have a solution for you, but I'm going to suggest a change to your `PollImage` method to make it more Rx-like.

The signature should look like this:

```
IObservable<Image> PollImage(string imageUri, TimeSpan gapInterval)
```

You should consider `PollImage` to be an observable factory, and it won't actually poll for images until you subscribe to the returned observable. The advantage with this approach is that it makes unsubscribing possible - your last bullet point requires this - and it cleanly separates the code that polls for images and the code that updates the local variables.

So, the call to `PollImage` then looks like this:

```
PollImage(imageUri, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200.0))
    .Subscribe(image =>
    {
        /* do save/update images here */
    });
```

And the implementation looks like this:

```
private IObservable<Image> PollImage(string imageUri, TimeSpan gapInterval)
{
    Func<Stream, Image> getImageFromStream = st =>
    {
        /* read image from stream here */
    };

    return Observable.Create<Image>(o =>
    {
        if (_channel == null)
        {
            _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        }

        var getImageFunc =
            Observable
                .FromAsyncPattern<string, Stream>(
                    _channel.BeginGetImage,
                    _channel.EndGetImage);

        var query =
            from ts in Observable.Timer(gapInterval)
            from stream in getImageFunc(imageUri)
            from img in Observable.Using(
                () => stream,
                st => Observable.Start(
                    () => getImageFromStream(st)))
            select img;

        return query.Do(img => { }, ex =>
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
            ((ICommunicationObject)_channel).CloseOrAbort();
            _channel = null;
        }).Repeat().Retry().Subscribe(o);                   
    });
}
```

The `query` observable waits until the `gapInterval` is complete and then calls the WCF function to return the stream and then converts the stream to an image.

The inner `return` statement does a number of things.

First it uses a `Do` operator to capture any exceptions that occur and does your tracing and channel reset as before.

Next it calls `.Repeat()` to cause query to be re-run effectively making it wait `gapInterval` before calling the webservice again. I could have used `Observable.Interval` rather than `Observable.Timer` in `query` and drop the call to `.Repeat()`, but this would have meant the calls to the webservice start every `gapInterval` rather than wait that long after it completed last time.

Next it calls `.Retry()` which effectively restarts the observable if it encounters an exception so that the subscriber never sees the exception. The `Do` operator captures the errors so this is OK.

Finally it subscribes the observer and returns the `IDisposable` allowing the calling code to unsubscribe.

Other than implementing the `getImageFromStream` function, that's about it.

Now a word of caution. A lot of people misunderstand how subscribing to observables works and this can lead to hard to discover bugs.

Take this as an example:

```
var xs = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

var s1 = xs.Subscribe(x => { });
var s2 = xs.Subscribe(x => { });
```

Both `s1` & `s2` subscribe to `xs`, but rather than share a single timer they each create a timer. You have two instances of the internal workings of `Observable.Interval` created, not one.

Now this is the correct behaviour for observables. In the event that one fails then the other won't because they don't share any internals - they are isolated from each other.

However, in your code (and mine for that matter) you have a potential threading issue because you share `_channel` across multiple calls to `PollImage`. If one call fails it resets the channel and this can cause concurrent calls to then fail as a result.

My suggestion is that you create a new channel for each call to prevent concurrency issues.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer & thanks. I like your use of query expressions. I have got rid of the shared channel now as well. I will post my latest attempt shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with (with some help!)... still not "perfect" but seems to work.

As @Enigma said I've got rid of the shared _channel now and replaced it with a captured local var. It works but I don't understand Rx enuf to know if this is poor/buggy approach. I suspect there is a cleaner way at least.

Other than that, my main objection is the Do() where I call EnsureChannel... seems a bit smelly. But... it works...

Oh and I must have the _ (underscore) in the SelectMany or else the GetImage is not called again.

```
    private IDisposable PollImage(string imageUri)
    {
        ICameraServiceAsync channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2))
            .Do(_ => { channel = EnsureChannel(channel); })
            .SelectMany(_ =>
                Observable
                .FromAsyncPattern<string, Stream>(channel.BeginGetImage, channel.EndGetImage)(imageUri))
            .Retry()
            .Repeat()
            .Subscribe(stream => UpdateImageStream(imageUri, stream));
    }

    private ICameraServiceAsync EnsureChannel(ICameraServiceAsync channel)
    {
        var icc = channel as ICommunicationObject;
        if (icc != null)
        {
            var communicationState = icc.State; // Copy local for debug inspection
            if (communicationState == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                icc.CloseOrAbort();
                channel = null;
            }
        }
        return channel ?? _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

Comment: What you've done is fairly OK - the `Do` for ensuring the channel is good. however, you are not disposing of your streams. You'd see in my solution I had the `Observable.Using` method call that did that. Also you're not handling exceptions now. And the only thing that is a smell now is that you're creating the observable and subscribing to it in the one function - doing that isn't composible - you can't intercept the stream of images and you have created code which is difficult to test because of the strong coupling.

Comment: Good feedback. I've made it composable now. I am disposing of the stream elsewhere (another thread) so I cant dispose of it here I think. What do you think of capturing local channel variable? Is there a better Rx way to do it? I tried Start() then pass it in the pipeline but had some problems.

Comment: Make sure you use `Observable.Create` rather than going straight into `Observable.Timer` now that you're composible. As for the `EnsureChannel` method, how about just make it do this: `ICameraServiceAsync CreateChannel()`? I don't like that you're creating the channel in two places when it can just be in one.

Comment: Ah, will all the subscribers currently share the same Timer? May not be bad in my case but something to watch for

Comment: Reason to do EnsureChannel is that sometimes I dont want to create a new one if the existing one is OK. If I remove param, then it cant access the captured local var

Comment: There is a brand new Timer created for every value produced by `PollImage` - and that's how it should be because you want to have a constant gap between calls. If you change `ICameraServiceAsync channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();` to `ICameraServiceAsync channel = null` then the channel creation would only be in one place and the code will function just fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use then people have already answered your question and if you are looking for alternate ways then I would suggest have a look at TPL (Task etc objects) that allows you to create task object from a Async method pattern (your web service call) and then start the task with a cancellation token so that after some time if the task is not completed you can cancel it by calling token cancel method.

Comment: I passed over TPL because it doesnt seem to have such advanced compositional abilities as Rx

Comment: Seems like people to down vote without giving a comment (don't want to share their knowledge probably) :)